# best way to join ears?

Tags: modeling

HI I would like a method to join the ear to the mesh , I do not want many polygons in my whole object, I consider the rings of the edge loops must be the same size as possible, the ear has a 18 vertices around and the hole in the face of the character has only 11 ve[image]rt, should I need to merge vertices, but nasty problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- Place the ear in the perfect position.
- Select the both the ear and head mesh using `shift+right click`
- Hit `ctrl+J` to join the the two meshes together
- you can then enter edit mode select vertices and choose `smooth vertices` from the tools menu